# What are the root causes of modern anti-Mexican sentiment in America?

Tags: united-states, racism

From reading [Wikipedia's Anti-Mexican Sentiment Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Mexican_sentiment), it appears that America's modern [Hispanophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hispanophobia) stems from

> [The] Texas Revolution and Texas annexation, [where] the United States inherited border disputes of the [[Republic of Texas]] with Mexico.

---

So, did American Hispanophobia start due to the aftereffects of the Texas Revolution and Texas annexation over 150 years ago?

Or is modern Anti-Mexican Sentiment not primarily a continuation of those aftereffects? If so, what is the root cause of Anti-Mexican Sentiment, then?

Comment: A study of the journals of American trappers and other explorers along the frontier between Mexico and the USA in the early 1800's, prior to the Texas Revolution shows there was already distrust and ill-treatment by both sides towards the other.

Comment: I think you have to first show that there in fact is such a thing as Hispanophobia, as distinguished from concerns about (mostly illegal) immigration.  That is, a century or so ago we had "Eireophobia", and "Chinaphobia", and if today's immigrants were coming in the same numbers from say Russia, we'd instead be discussing "Russophobia".

Comment: @jamesqf - Yeah, part of my draft of this question... then I cut it out and now I forget how I phrased it, so it'll be a bit before I can add it back in... ... I gotta go, if you could edit it for me, that'd be great, but I'll be back in 3hrs at the most... So, yeah...

Comment: @hatchet - Do you have any links to those sources? So I can add them to this question and make it more accurate?

Comment: If I had links, I would have made it an answer instead of a comment. What I have is well over 100 journals and narratives from the trapping era, but they are books in my library, so hard to link to. Read how the Mexican authorities treated the early Americans in California...James O. Pattie for instance, or look at the origins of the derogatory term "greasers" which Mt. Men were using for Mexicans prior to the Texas Rev.

Comment: @Malandy - It definitely predates Texas Revolution.  You could start from reading the wikipedia article on "Black legend" and the sources it cites in the Notes section.